# Apache httpd 2.4.57 error during pre-check of source code

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

i've used this command

./configure --enable-ssl  --enable-so  --with-mpm=event  --with-included-apr  --prefix=/etc/httpd

someone has an idea how to install  the rustl version on centos 8 ?

the error i receive --> "checking for pkg-config along ... checking for rustls version >= 0.8.2... FAILED
no"

what i've tried is installing cargo and then use the command cargo install rustls without success

on system appear latest version

cargo search rustls:
rustls = "0.21.0"                          # Rustls is a modern TLS library

Comment: Hi, please use code formatting: read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, why all these extra newlines? Remember, well formatted questions are more likely to get answers